# How to override the text in Twitter Digits android?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

In twitter digits https://github.com/twitter/digits-android while verifying phone number there's an activity for Entering the confirmation code in which there's an EditText and a Button for "SIGN IN".

My question is how to change the text of the button from "Sign in" ?

Because Twitter Digits allows only changing the theme. 
And all of these tasks are being done by Twitter-digits sdk.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must to override the strings from Digits, for example in the Auth button you must to have this on res/values/strings.xml:

```
<string name="dgts__login_digits_text">Validate</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

As of now, Twitter Fabric Digits has not officially provided support to amend this. You should not change anything that is not documented by the Digits team as then you will always run in the risk of having an obsolete code.